# Permission to open camera denied - SDK29 - React Native Project

Tags: android, react-native

After changing the SDK to 29, the camera that used to open normally on 28 is now denied permission.

My project is developed in "react-native": "0.59.9".

Here is some additional information:

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "15.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()

        // ADD THIS
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        
        
        // ADD THIS
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}


wrapper{
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

[image]

warning:

[image]

I point out to anyone who is reading that I followed the guidelines of this article https://www.reactnativeschool.com/how-to-upgrade-react-native-app-to-api-level-29, however, after the procedure I am facing the problem with the camera.

Has anyone faced a problem like this? Would they know how to guide me how to proceed?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: ok, but do you have the answer to this issue?